# What to say when fasting 3 days to break oath?

Tags: sawm, food, oaths

I wonder when you fast for 3 days to take back an oath on not eating something because you realize that thing is in everything. Is there something that has to be recited to make it clear that you take back the oath or do you tell God that you will fast for 3 days because of that cause to take back the oath on that particular thing. Sorry if this sounds complicated, grateful for answer.

Comment: Doesn't Allah know everythimg even our deepest secrets?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you shouldnt say anything, in fact its an innovation (bid'a) to do so..

All you have to do is to have the intention (niyyah) of fasting this day as a kaffarah, just as simple as it is

**Note** You mustnt fast except if you're unable to feed, clothe, or free

> Allah will not call you to account for your thoughtless oaths, but He will hold you accountable for deliberate oaths. **The penalty for a broken oath is to feed ten poor people from what you normally feed your own family, or to clothe them, or to free a bondsperson. But if none of this is affordable, then you must fast three days.** This is the penalty for breaking your oaths. So be mindful of your oaths. This is how Allah makes things clear to you, so perhaps you will be grateful. [5:89]